# Does leaving the excess string uncut, affect the guitar's tone?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, strings, tone

I mean negatively or positively. I have seen lots of people do that. And I saw on one place that it's just that they want to look rebely or something like that.
But, I asked this from a music teacher and though she doesn't know about guitars very well, she said that the tone might get colored somehow. I also think it might as the wood, bridge, frets also affect the guitar's final tone.
Any thoughts?

Comment: It's all fun and games until someone looses an eye.

Comment: Tom Morello still got his. :)

Comment: Serious question: Why would one worry about this? Also negative/positive difference is very subjective.

Comment: @Ye Dawg Yeah but, if you look around the site, you'll notice more 'subjective' kinda questions. And some people prefer the sound of tube amps while other it's the solid states. But when it is taken overally, there are some aspects of music that are considered.. pleasing and not. So, it's also subjective that the people think this is not that something to worry about or not.    But hey, please don't listen to above with a rough tone applied.

Answer (score 10):

No difference. The strings vibrate from where they're fretted, or the nut when open, to the saddles on the bridge. If they had a centimetre or a metre hanging off - no difference, apart from getting in the way, or vibrating against something else causing annoyance.

Comment: but, just like the qualities of the nut, frets, soundboard. bridge all affect the tone..?

Comment: @user152435 Those things _can_ affect the tone _only if_ they affect how the string vibrates. If the nut is doing a reasonable job of keeping its end of the string stationary, then nothing on "the other side" of the nut is going to affect how the string vibrates.

Comment: @user152435 - try this: play something - open strings if you like, and hold the head tightly. You'll find there's no difference in anything. Those string ends are in the same vicinity. Try holding them! No change.

Answer (score 4):

You could probably make precise scientific measurements and find a tiny effect - maybe positive, maybe negative.   But practically, no.

In the same way as 'oxygen-free copper' may be measured as slightly superior for audio cables.  VERY slightly.

Comment: The effect is probably not quite so tiny as oxygen-free copper, but probably still smaller than e.g. cable _capacitance_.